# Hibernate :Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, hibernate

I have used many to one bidirectional relationship here I can't delete the files once i have been had into database if I am trying to delete I am getting exception has Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.treamis.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;

/**
 *
 * @author
 * admin
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "LibraryBookListTable")
public class LibraryBookListEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "BookListId")
    private int booklistid;
    @Column(name = "ISBN", nullable = false)
    private String isbn;
    @Column(name = "edition", nullable = false)
    private String edition;
    @Column(name = "publisher", nullable = false)
    private String publisher;
    @Column(name = "place", nullable = false)
    private String place;
    @Column(name = "page", nullable = false)
    private String page;
    @Column(name = "source", nullable = false)
    private String source;
    @Column(name = "billno", nullable = false)
    private String billno;
    @Column(name = "callno", nullable = false)
    private String callno;
    @Column(name = "BookTitle", nullable = false)
    private String booktitle;
    @Column(name = "BookAuthor", nullable = false)
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "BookPrice", nullable = false)
    private float price;
    @Column(name = "RackNumber", nullable = false)
    private String rack;
    @Column(name = "PublishedYear", nullable = false)
    private String publishedyear;
    @Column(name = "NoofCopies", nullable = false)
    private int tcopies;
    @Column(name = "DateAdded", nullable = false)
    private java.sql.Date dateAdded;
    @Column(name = "billdate", nullable = false)
    private java.sql.Date billdate;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = CategoryEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_Id", referencedColumnName = "category_Id", nullable = true)
    private CategoryEntity categoryid;
    @OneToOne
    private UserEntity addedBy;
    @OneToOne
    private UserEntity modifiedBy;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = LibraryBarCodeEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "S_no")
    @JoinColumn(name = "BookListId", referencedColumnName = "BookListId")
    private Set< LibraryBarCodeEntity> chield;

    public Set<LibraryBarCodeEntity> getChield() {
        return chield;
    }

    public void setChield(Set<LibraryBarCodeEntity> chield) {
        this.chield = chield;
    }
    //@Column(name = "AddedDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date addedate;
    // @Column(name = "ModifiedDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date modifiedDate;

    public int getBooklistid() {
        return booklistid;
    }

    public void setBooklistid(int booklistid) {
        this.booklistid = booklistid;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getBooktitle() {
        return booktitle;
    }

    public void setBooktitle(String booktitle) {
        this.booktitle = booktitle;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getRack() {
        return rack;
    }

    public void setRack(String rack) {
        this.rack = rack;
    }

    public int getTcopies() {
        return tcopies;
    }

    public void setTcopies(int tcopies) {
        this.tcopies = tcopies;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(java.sql.Date dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public CategoryEntity getCategoryid() {
        return categoryid;
    }

    public void setCategoryid(CategoryEntity categoryid) {
        this.categoryid = categoryid;
    }

    public UserEntity getAddedBy() {
        return addedBy;
    }

    public void setAddedBy(UserEntity addedBy) {
        this.addedBy = addedBy;
    }

    public UserEntity getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(UserEntity modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public java.util.Date getAddedate() {
        return addedate;
    }

    public void setAddedate(java.util.Date addedate) {
        this.addedate = addedate;
    }

    public java.util.Date getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(java.util.Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

//    public String getAccessionnumber() {
//        return accessionnumber;
//    }
//
//    public void setAccessionnumber(String accessionnumber) {
//        this.accessionnumber = accessionnumber;
//    }
    public String getEdition() {
        return edition;
    }

    public void setEdition(String edition) {
        this.edition = edition;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getBillno() {
        return billno;
    }

    public void setBillno(String billno) {
        this.billno = billno;
    }

    public String getCallno() {
        return callno;
    }

    public void setCallno(String callno) {
        this.callno = callno;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getBilldate() {
        return billdate;
    }

    public void setBilldate(java.sql.Date billdate) {
        this.billdate = billdate;
    }

    public String getPublishedyear() {
        return publishedyear;
    }

    public void setPublishedyear(String publishedyear) {
        this.publishedyear = publishedyear;
    }
//    public Set< LibraryBarCodeEntity> getChield() {
//        return chield;
//    }
//
//    public void setChield(Set< LibraryBarCodeEntity> chield) {
//        this.chield = chield;
//    }
}
```

This is my another entity class..

```
package com.treamis.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author
 * admin
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "LibraryBarCodeTable")
public class LibraryBarCodeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "S_no", nullable = false)
    private int S_no;
    @Column(name = "BookBarCode", nullable = false)
    private String barCode;
    private String accessno;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = LibraryBookListEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BookListId", referencedColumnName = "BookListId")
    private LibraryBookListEntity parent;

    public LibraryBookListEntity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(LibraryBookListEntity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getS_no() {
        return S_no;
    }

    public void setS_no(int S_no) {
        this.S_no = S_no;
    }

    public String getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    public void setBarCode(String barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

    public String getAccessno() {
        return accessno;
    }

    public void setAccessno(String accessno) {
        this.accessno = accessno;
    }
}
```

Hi this is my complete stack trace

```
2014-01-09 15:44:26 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`treamisdemo`.`librarybooklisttable`, CONSTRAINT `FK33BC700C2F4991AA` FOREIGN KEY (`category_Id`) REFERENCES `categoryentity` (`category_Id`))
2014-01-09 15:44:26 ERROR AbstractFlushingEventListener:301 - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.treamis.library.BookList.LibraryBookListDelete.execute(LibraryBookListDelete.java:90)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
```

Comment: So, what is the code that is causing the exception, and what's the complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: hi can u just see my update.

Comment: The stack trace you posted doesn't talk about foreign key constraints at all. What's the *actual* stack trace, and the code causing this exception to be thrown?

Comment: For the third time: what is the code causing this exception, i.e. the code of `com.treamis.library.BookList.LibraryBookListDelete.execute()`?

Comment: yes can u just tell me whts the problem in it.

Comment: I can't explain why your code is wrong without even seeing the code. Since you were asked to show it three times already, but didn't bother to do so, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of this will help, but if you haven't already done so, you can edit your hibernate.cfg.xml file and set hibernate.show_sql from false to true in order to see what sql statements are generated when the exception occurs. Examining them may provide you a clue on what is going on. You may also consider putting print statements (System.out.println) in your set*() functions to see what primary and foreign key values are so you can examine the data in the database (now that you know the primary key value, you can see what record is being processed).
Example: System.out.println("in MyDaoClass: calling customer table: setId()="+customer.getID());